# Jinja2 failing to import on Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, jinja2

I am going through the Google App Engine tutorial for python 2.7 and I have hit a road block.  I am unable to get jinja2 to import, so every time I add import jinja2 to my code, the application fails to load.

I have installed jinja2 locally as well, and no luck.  I'm not sure what else to do, I've been looking around for a while and nothing I have read seems to help.

Comment: Show us the stacktrace. Does this occur locally, or in production?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add library dependency in your app.yaml

Example:

```
libraries:
- name: jinja2
  version: latest
- name: markupsafe
  version: latest
- name: django
  version: latest
```